# mocha - send json to post express route

Tags: json, node.js, post, express, mocha.js

I'm trying to send some json data to my `'/sign_up'` route in mocha test.

```
request = require 'supertest'
express = require 'express'
app = express()
Authentication = require("#{specDir}/../apps/authentication/routes")
authenticate = new Authentication app

Factory = require "#{specDir}/factories/user"
user = Factory.build 'user'
  it 'creates an account', (done) ->
    request(app).post('/sign_up').set('Accept', 'application/json').send(user).end (err, res) ->
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal 200
      done()
```

However `req.body` in the callback function is `undefined`. Below I've shown a snippet of my route callback

```
  @app.post '/sign_up', (req, res) ->
    res.format
      html: -> res.status(406).send 'invalid Content-Type'
      json: ->
        console.log req.body
        res.status(200).send status: 'ok'
```

Probably I'm missing some small detail, but can't see what.. any ideas?

P.S. I'm well aware of that the tests pass and it does what it should, but before I move on to write more tests I gotta know how to send some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a body parser, add `app.use(express.json())` in your code somewhere.